# Wheels look sliding instead of rotating

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I added a polaris ranger model and set the joint velocities, the car moves but the wheels look sliding instead of rotating. I'm a bit confused and I want to understand how the stuff work ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2273/wheels-look-sliding-instead-of-rotating./) by [amine23](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/301/amine23/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-09**:
Please check that you are using revolute joint not revolute2.

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/301/amine23/) on 2013-04-09**:
@skhan I checked the sdf file and the joint is of type revolute not revolute2.
My intuition says if we rotate a joint, the links attached to it will also rotate (and do so the visuals of the link, hence the link will look rotating, which is not the case here). This is confusig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is fixed in gazebo 1.6. A pending pull-request for an updated polaris model will finalize the sliding wheels problem.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0